# Unable to download video from Google Photos API baseUrl

Tags: google-photos-api

I am trying to download a video from {baseUrl=dv}. ( [URL 1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/AJ_cxPbUfqcrm_CsqFFjDGQifyxrZyPP500kGyJFg-vs0zDJCepwj7onzSPpVrkiqgKA_Xjm9qfYRf2b32pOa6os7hAiN2yHeQ0XcIfL5nAkOPl_sPeuslNbIpUJnW5HzFGw5OrnI8Un_7JAHm-tDqDG5uBJeTgCP_HQ2K07qm4J5OZhravlVI8K0ORcbH7QtUnRqd3KCp8DjfWrX2kP6N2bR7EVwgBkaxmlsxMzjiRb8J1ryUNGOK2xZXStDd1qg8IpzWv3iYIkLImrRlFJH4Ilvme_Tk7zdUOqTguF8LqRRsrKY-qL0aoUeKt1kcvIYBOXGRjee9--Pq5COdumJ0VNstt8siHvaOsLegT5nAavjnc43kiV_4sQxtkgAHdPY723hv1WJAzESdExKtHJl2PbmdxkcG-jUdnEBw7sBP9-IXXTNC-W64ZN0NDOnsjKBZ_UjcfU2FefaFVYfhfRpqZRCjEOqTqqm1kOmrDRBBQDS8pT8Pdv_Kdl4-0YV6rK-UifK34tJTt4081DYpkWc0zyzYus8kFB07wTRQWcspXdrnEFzb3px5z3KOwuuatkjX2blFCTV7Nh3p5phzxghIM9H5XgRb1IMryrJ7YOfni-r4v6YJjhaJQNTbV5KCn0NxFCW1tsWpvC7sLCyrFVOSn4VZno_oH1qfvIH-BLee4SwOXSvcQ5M05kDKsrIYkhgSlnUNykkExsz2ywcSpX7llfvMuWQOWkJWU2CPc1yQM0wTz8lK444PEALCYXkxTO1PC7pvfboT8NdGwmq7bLVZQXl2nVNlviuaxrCs2_ShVF1DMXK6BUPAiRiEO6tJQeKzScnkQzfvOnrQ=dv) )

After that the page on this URL was redirected and getting a 500 error ( [URL 2](https://video-downloads.googleusercontent.com/ADwZHhMu9QMBbzuVFJh1SrrgYLUnUk-nI2yohCffvy0cFWpR4HNys8vxej-IFYLt6sZr2B_M_bdokdwY1Ij6vGeogKeju91gF3V5_yKnX4-8m_4iBzyTjHns_ThB-QWy-05WGOprmH567LvcvoCxQH9on8x1rSfi6lavv5AT0_cHnFCEjKFNCA4wmmB1GA2Umr13DZbTebd6pQ8OtOTd_xgmJ-5zsbBQjt11lOS42LJrF0nOiloot7_cYoFLLCHbphJ3_Mc0euFL1-yJYuB8jDQnHLZFZW1ER-5GybeHFyu6BV4qHFXAB5wHG2ehESuSAj-zqsQvKZNd7iH2S8zG4jMmB7UEwrMXC-kngJXkkZRZPTjL_UeqzKHAd-KaNODBlYSo5V_r-kW8rfUuJq3JBkpmm12BMl31EIwHQTS65aHnPD_gdm_Guoc-4tuZnEX9AgjuV8xiZvTH8K7vksBhh972WoAhGx1l13goPCb_7jJTmUWOM24_lJcMB2Elo8n-D0Xlb_L-Ux0KkBWCQ6bRwILJXfF8OsxfwjnhzqKIcNj68mzL1fyhc8UFNXJOU45DdUHO3phCAOqozLbCNq0FzIjQgBLuD7H6mG55_Ah5qHP-9oCU3j0wgoIBasWakiPWf_i1Gblmpiup1ZQsv_x_tIF9rX2Y0WQ5U9ZAjGOUE8pEstQnJ11r6b1jRduHrt3Oiizqa5mghNbhJxCshv06VcXHKomKQ6Jab8fvavTkWKtEU6kyX7_4UlMo2GNDTUFi3sLz7gAMJhoY) ).

What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a known issue with base URLs for videos. Accessing the video via the `dv` parameter returns a 500 Error.

You can follow along on the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/111638708 ("Star" the issue to be notified of any updates.)